# Push notifications ios

Tags: c#, ios, swift

Gostaria de adicionar push notifications ao meu app, gostaria que alguém pudesse me explicar como seria todo esse processo visto que os dados entram num banco SQL Server e meu app recebe esses dados via api json e não tem acesso ao banco.

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Qual é a relação de C# com iOS e Swift? ._.

Comment: A base do meu sistema é em C# creio que para disparar essas notificações terei que criar uma aplicação C# que mande as informações para o servidor de Push notifications ou estou errado??

Comment: Boa tarde @JulioFigueiredo , cara da uma olhada no Firebase, lá você pode utilizar o serviço de mensagens - FCM. É possível utilizar para apps IOS e o seu backend mesmo sendo em C# consegue interagir com o serviço do google para notificar o seu app. Qualquer dúvidas só chamar. Ah o serviço de mensagens é free :)

https://firebase.google.com/products/cloud-messaging/?hl=pt-br

Comment: @ArthurCordovaStapassoli olhei sim, fiz até uma conta na Amazon também, o que eu não sei é como começar isso, se tiver algum tutorial para mim dar uma olhada agradeço, já vi varios sobre como implementar no app, mas não acho nada sobre como enviar aqui da minha parte de onde os dados estão armazenados por exemplo. Tenho um sistema em C# que corrigi provas, toda vez que um nova prova for corrigida gostaria de notificar cada aluno, então eu consigo fazer a minha aplicação c# conversar com o servidor Firebase??, seria isto??

Comment: Isso mesmo, seu backend consegue conversar com o servidor Firebase e ai notificar o app. Vou postar um tutorial de como eu fiz logo em seguida.

Comment: @ArthurCordovaStapassoli  legal fico no aguardo do tutorial

Answer (score 1):

Olha amigo, sua pergunta ta um pouco difícil de entender, porém, pra fazer push notifications você pode usar o OneSignal que tem suporte pra tudo hoje em dia, Xcode, Android Studio, Unity etc.

OneSignal: https://onesignal.com/

Comment: Wendel não conhecia, dei uma olhada no site deles e agora vou procurar algum tutorial pra implementar isso aí, se tiver algum bom aí e quiser me passar agradeço

Comment: Tem bastante tutorial perdido por ai, e a documentação deles é bem completa. Só vai jovem!